# Alias Entry in /etc/passwd file

Tags: linux, redhat, passwd

On my desktop machine, my account is `david`, but on my servers it's `dweintra`. This means whenever I use `scp` I have to do this:

```
$ scp some.file dweintra@app05:
```

and

```
$ ssh dweinta@app05
```

I'd like to be able to simply do this:

```
$ scp some.file app05:
$ ssh app05
```

That is, somehow create an `david`*alias* user name to my actual `dweintra` user name. I figure i could do this by putting an entry in the `/etc/passwd` file that matches the `dweintra` entry except of course for the first field of the line.

The `dweintra` is actually in NIS and not directly in `/etc/passwd`. Would there any problems doing this?

I'm just hoping to cut down on a few keystrokes and the few brief milliseconds it takes for me to pull what my user name is on the server.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tell your ssh client which username to use when connecting to remote hosts. Put this in .ssh/config on your workstation:

```
Host *
User dweinta
```

I recommend you read all of the man page for ssh_config while you're at it.

Comment: On the Mac, it's `User` and not `Username`. Probably a BSD vs. Linux thing.

Comment: Nope, that was just me remembering wrong. Fixed.